# PDF from URL is not opening in Modal POP UP in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have requirement when I click on button it opens the POP up and in that PDF get loaded from URL within that pop up and on close button pop up get closed.
So below is my code it is working fine on desktop in all browsers. But on mobile in chrome, Microsoft edge it is not opening PDF and showing content is blocked. In Safari and Firefox on mobile it opening fine. Opera it is showing download option directly.

So I want to preview PDF in Modal pop up and on close of that I want to enable that submit button. I have added site in CSP as well.

```
       <template if:true={isModalOpen}>
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium">
                    PDF Viewer
                </h2>
            </header>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="modalContent">
                    <iframe src={pdfLink} width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={closeModal}>Close</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```